# Always bind docker-compose network to the same internal container interface

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose file that creates two internal interface for a pihole docker container. One network interface is being utilised for communication between the different containers (including a reserve proxy for the pihole interface) and the other interface is within the IP range of my internal network (192.168.2.0) serving the DHCP and DNS service that the pihole service provides.

DHCP requests should be always served to this specific interface which is hardwired in the DHCP (DNSMASQ) configuration file. From time to time I have to recreate the container (i.e., image updates) and it seems to be completely random if the DHCP serving interface is being generated as eth0 or eth1.

Is it possible to preset the interface in the docker-compose file or anywhere else to it's always either eth0 or eth1?

```
networks:
  pihole_network:                    
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth2                  
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.2.1
          ip_range: 192.168.2.50/32

services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest 
    ports:
    - "53:53/tcp"
    - "192.168.2.199:53:53/udp"
    - "67:67/udp"
    - "8081:8080/tcp"
    - "30001:443/tcp"
    networks:
      pihole_network: 
        ipv4_address: 192.168.2.50
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 8.8.8.8
    environment:
      ServerIP: 192.168.2.50  
      TZ: 'Europe/Zurich'
      WEBPASSWORD: 'XXX'
      DHCP_ACTIVE: 'false'
      WEBTHEME: 'default-dark'
      WEB_PORT: 8081
      DNSMASQ_USER: 'root'
    labels:
      // LABELS // 
    volumes:
      // VOLUMES // 
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
```

Just as fyi, the second network (the bridge network for cross container communication) is just being connected through one time docker container which connects the container to the bridge

```
  connect-bridge:
    image: stmllr/docker-client
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
        - pihole
    command: /bin/sh -c 'docker ps -f label=networks=bridge --format "{{.ID}}" | xargs docker network connect bridge pihole'
```

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4645) and [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/43518)

Comment: just to understand your case: you have containers attached to default bridge network and pihole container that acts as DHCP and DNS server for these containers, right? default route for containers on default bridge network is something like: `default via xxx.yy.0.1 dev eth0` but not all the times, is this your problem?

Comment: Could you add some details on the network configuration of one container served by pihole?

Comment: Could you add your daemon.json configuration?